# cross-reference with second level items

Tags: cross-referencing, lists, enumerate

In the following situation

```
\begin{enumerate}

\item 

\begin{enumerate}

\item \label{ii}

\item

\end{enumerate}

\item

\end{enumerate}

Item \ref{ii}
```

I obtain in the output

1. (a)

(b)

2.

Item 1a

I want, however, to obtain "Item (a)" (the reference should contain only the second-level item number, not the first level). How can I do it?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).  Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts.

Answer (score 4):

The `enumitem` package allows one to customise list environments and their parameters.

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item 
    \begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*),ref=\alph*]
    \item \label{ii}
    \item
    \end{enumerate}
\item
\end{enumerate}

Item \ref{ii}
```

In the snippet above the argument of `enumerate` allows you to set how the label and the reference to it will be printed. It is possible to set the parameter globally. To set a parameter globally one can use the command

```
\setlist[list,level]{format}
```

where `list` is one of  `description`, `enumerate` or `itemize`; or

```
\setlist[level]{format}
```

Thus for the case at hand

```
\setlist[enumerate,2]{ref=\alph*]
```

See the package documentation (`texdoc enumitem`).