# How to change the appearance of \ref depending on where it's called relative to the \label

Tags: cross-referencing

I have defined a `\task` sectioning command and a `subtasks`-list as in this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\usepackage[loadonly, explicit]{titlesec}

\titleclass{\task}[1]{straight}
\newcounter{task}
\titleformat{\task}
    [hang]{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{Task \thetask:}{1ex}{#1}
\titlespacing*{\task}
    {0pt}{3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{0ex plus .2ex}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{subtasks}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[subtasks]{label=\alph*),%
    ref=\thetask\,\alph*),%
    format=\normalfont\large\bfseries,%
    itemsep=1.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex,%
    before=\newcommand{\subtask}{\item},%
    after=\vspace{0.5ex}}

\begin{document}


\task{first task}
\begin{subtasks}

    \subtask\label{some_subtask}
    Some subtask

    \subtask
    I am referencing \ref{some_subtask}.

\end{subtasks}

\task{another task}
I am referencing \ref{some_subtask} again.


\end{document}
```

[image: The output of the MWE above]

What I would like to do is to have the `\ref` appear differently depending on if it is called in the same `\task` as the `\label` (just as "a)") or not (as "1 a)" as above).
It should also be compatible to `hyperref`.

Is this possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94318/cross-reference-with-second-level-items

Comment: @TheExplosiveSheep, I don't believe it is a duplicate. The OP wants to change the output depending if the `\ref` is inside/outside the environment. Only changing the format of the labels is not enough.

Comment: You might want to take a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/187105/references-to-floats-without-ever-using-figure-numbers-possbily-using-lua-or-py/187359#187359

Comment: I thought I could use xstring to decompose 1\,a), but even something as simple as \edef\temp{\ref{some_subtask}} causes an error.  This is not normal behavior! (later) Aha! hyperref is the culprit.  Even ref* doesn't work.

Answer (score 5):

[image: refsub]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\usepackage[loadonly, explicit]{titlesec}

\titleclass{\task}[1]{straight}
\newcounter{task}
\titleformat{\task}
    [hang]{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{Task \thetask:}{1ex}{#1}
\titlespacing*{\task}
    {0pt}{3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{0ex plus .2ex}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{subtasks}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[subtasks]{label=\alph*),%
    ref=\thetask.\alph*,%
    format=\normalfont\large\bfseries,%
    itemsep=1.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex,%
    before=\newcommand{\subtask}{\item},%
    after=\vspace{0.5ex}}

\usepackage{xstring}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\refsub}[1]% #1 = label name for subtasks
{\@ifundefined{r@#1}{??}{\begingroup%
  \edef\temp{\expandafter\detokenize\getrefnumber{#1}}%
  \StrCut{\temp}{.}\temptask\tempsub%
  \edef\templink{\getrefbykeydefault{#1}{anchor}{}}%
  \if\thetask\temptask\hyperlink{\templink}{\tempsub)}%
  \else\hyperlink{\templink}{\temptask\,\tempsub)}\fi
\endgroup}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\task{first task}
\begin{subtasks}

    \subtask\label{some_subtask}
    Some subtask

    \subtask
    I am referencing \refsub{some_subtask}.

\end{subtasks}

\task{another task}
I am referencing \refsub{some_subtask} again.

\end{document}
```