# Provide only relevant context when printing section number in a cross-reference

Tags: cross-referencing

I inserted a number of cross-references to different parts of my book. Currently, I simply do so by calling a self-defined macro:

```
\newcommand\secref[1]{See \ref{#1}, \nameref{#1}.}
```

This will print a reference such as the following:

> See § 3:III.C.2.a), History and Institutions

Thus, the reference to the number, printed by `\ref`, includes `chapter` number, `section` number, `subsection` number, `subsubsection` number and `paragraph` number. Note that I defined my own numbering scheme using `alnumsec`.

What I want to achieve now is to make `\secref` aware of its relative position with regards to the label that is being referenced. If the `\secref` macro for the "History and Institutions" paragraph is called in chapter "§ 3", for instance, the `\ref` or a replacement command should only print "III.C.2.a)". If the `\secref` macro is called in chapter "§ 3", section "III", it should only print "C.2.a)", and so on.

But if the macro is called in, let's say, section "III" of chapter "§ 4", it should print "3: III.C.2.a)" In effect, I want to re-create a behaviour that can be found in Microsoft Word, where a cross-reference to a numbered paragraph will only print as much information as is necessary to make the reference unambiguous in the current context.

So unless a `chapter`,`section`,etc. number is provided, the reader can assume that the reference is a reference to different `section`,`subsection`,etc in the same `chapter`,`section`,etc.

Based on @JohnKormylo's comment below and his answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208958/how-to-change-the-appearance-of-ref-depending-on-where-its-called-relative-to?lq=1), I have prepared a MWE that tries to achieve what I want by using a custom `\secrefnumber` macro that parses the content of `\getrefnumber`, but I am still stuck because compiling the MWE will result in an error "Missing { inserted." (As regards the approach in the MWE: I am aware that the `\if\thechapter\temptask` will always yield a false because the `\temptask` does not include the colon; I was going to get to that once the MWE is working).

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{alnumsec}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\addto\captionsenglish{%
\renewcommand\chaptername{}}

\alnumsectionlevels{1}{chapter,section} 
\otherseparators{2}
\alnumsecstyle{aR}
\surroundarabic[][]{§ }{:}
\surroundRoman{}{.}

\makeatletter

\newcommand\secref[1]{\secrefnumber{#1}, \nameref{#1}.}

\newcommand{\secrefnumber}[1]{% #1 = label name for subtasks
\@ifundefined{r@#1}{??}{%
\begingroup%
  \edef\temp{\expandafter\detokenize\getrefnumber{#1}}%
  \StrCut{\temp}{:}\temptask\tempsub%
  \edef\templink{\getrefbykeydefault{#1}{anchor}{}}%
  \if\thechapter\temptask%
    \hyperlink{\templink}{\tempsub)}%
  \else%
    \hyperlink{\templink}{\temptask\,\tempsub)}%
  \fi
\endgroup%
}}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{My Very First Chapter}

\section{Introduction}
\label{sec:introduction}

\section{Once Upon a Time}

I am referencing \secref{sec:introduction}

\chapter{The Second Chapter}

I am referencing \secref{sec:introduction} again.

\end{document}
```

Comment: \ref, \nameref and \pageref are formatted (mostly) when the label is created, not when used.  So one would need to store all of the chapter, section etc. numbers separately.  This can be cone, but not using standard \labels.

Comment: That wouldn't be a problem. I can easily replace \label by any self-defined command.

Comment: A test MWE would help.  Some document classes and packages rename the counters.

Comment: Actually, using xstring it is possible to parse a \ref after all.  See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208958/how-to-change-the-appearance-of-ref-depending-on-where-its-called-relative-to/209218#209218

Comment: @JohnKormylo I tried creating a MWE showing where I would run into trouble applying your solution from http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208958/how-to-change-the-appearance-of-ref-depending-on-where-its-called-relative-to/209218#209218 but actually not even your MWE there works for me. pdflatex will always quit compiling with a host of errors, the first one being "Missing { inserted."

Comment: I found and fixed the bug.  I forgot to check if the label was defined yet.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Cheers for your help. Your solution to the other problem compiles for me now as well, but I can't get it adapted to my usage scenario. I have changed my question accordingly.

Comment: Have you looked at e.g. [smartref](http://ctan.org/pkg/smartref)?

Comment: Yes, but I don't think smartref can do that. At any rate, it is not implemented below chapter level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having trouble parsing \thechapter, so I created \seclabel to produce a simplified section label.

Evidently the \detokenize step wasn't needed here (I copied it originally from somewhere else).

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{alnumsec}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\addto\captionsenglish{%
\renewcommand\chaptername{}}

\alnumsectionlevels{1}{chapter,section} 
\otherseparators{2}
\alnumsecstyle{aR}
\surroundarabic[][]{§ }{:}
\surroundRoman{}{.}

\newcommand\secref[1]{\secrefnumber{#1}, \nameref{#1}.}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\seclabel}[1]{% #1 = label name
  \protected@edef\@currentlabel{\arabic{chapter}.\Roman{section}}%
  \label{#1}%
}

\newcommand{\secrefnumber}[1]{% #1 = label name
\@ifundefined{r@#1}{??}{%
\begingroup% use local definitions
  \edef\temp{\getrefnumber{#1}}% string containing \ref
  \StrCut{\temp}{.}\tempchap\temp% separate chapter
  \edef\templink{\getrefbykeydefault{#1}{anchor}{}}% \hyperlink anchor
  \if\arabic{chapter}\tempchap% same chapter
    \hyperlink{\templink}{\temp}%
  \else%
    \hyperlink{\templink}{§ \tempchap:\temp}%
  \fi
\endgroup%
}}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{My Very First Chapter}

\section{Introduction}
\seclabel{sec:introduction}

\section{Once Upon a Time}

I am referencing \secref{sec:introduction}

\chapter{The Second Chapter}

I am referencing \secref{sec:introduction} again.

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is brilliant. Cheers! I scaled your solution all the way to the subparagraph level. Yours is definitely the answer, but I am going to post my modification of your work just so people can see how to scale it all the way down.

Answer (score 0):

As I said, John Kormylo answered the question. I am going to include my modification of his answer that applies a scheme all the way down to the sub-paragraph level for reference's sake. Two things I noticed: the `etoolbox` test works more reliably, which is why I used that rather than a simple `\if`; second, `xstring` seems to do something funky to the strings, so I had to xstringify all current section values.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{alnumsec}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\addto\captionsenglish{%
\renewcommand\chaptername{}}

\makeatletter

\alnumsectionlevels{1}{chapter,section,subsection,subsubsection,paragraph,subparagraph} 
\otherseparators{2}
\alnumsecstyle{aRLald}
\surroundarabic[][.]{§ }{:}
\surroundLetter{}{.}
\surroundRoman{}{.}
\surroundletter{}{)}
\surrounddoubleletter{(}{)}
\surroundgreek{(}{)}

\newcommand\secref[1]{\secrefnumber{#1}\thinspace\enquote{\nameref{#1}}\thinspace\vpageref{#1}}

\@addtoreset{section}{chapter}

\@addtoreset{subsection}{chapter}
\@addtoreset{subsection}{section}

\@addtoreset{subsubsection}{chapter}
\@addtoreset{subsubsection}{section}
\@addtoreset{subsubsection}{subsection}

\@addtoreset{paragraph}{chapter}
\@addtoreset{paragraph}{section}
\@addtoreset{paragraph}{subsection}
\@addtoreset{paragraph}{subsubsection}

\@addtoreset{subparagraph}{chapter}
\@addtoreset{subparagraph}{section}
\@addtoreset{subparagraph}{subsection}
\@addtoreset{subparagraph}{subsubsection}
\@addtoreset{subparagraph}{paragraph}

\newcommand{\seclabel}[1]{%
  \protected@edef\@currentlabel{%
    \ifnumgreater{\value{chapter}}{0}{\arabic{chapter}}{}%
    \ifnumgreater{\value{section}}{0}{.\Roman{section}}{}%
    \ifnumgreater{\value{subsection}}{0}{.\Alph{subsection}}{}%
    \ifnumgreater{\value{subsubsection}}{0}{.\arabic{subsubsection}}{}%
    \ifnumgreater{\value{paragraph}}{0}{.\alph{paragraph}}{}%
    \ifnumgreater{\value{subparagraph}}{0}{.\alph{subparagraph}\alph{subparagraph}}{}%
   }%
  \label{#1}%
}

\newcommand{\secref@finaldelim}{:}
\newcommand{\secref@chapname}{§\thinspace }
\newcommand{\secref@secname}{section }
\newcommand{\secref@subname}{subsection }
\newcommand{\secref@subsname}{sub-subsection }
\newcommand{\secref@parname}{paragraph }
\newcommand{\secref@subparname}{subparagraph }

\newcommand{\secrefnumber}[1]{%
\@ifundefined{r@#1}{??}{%
\begingroup% use local definitions
  \edef\secref@name{\relax}%
  \edef\secref@text{\relax}%
  \edef\secref@rest{\getrefnumber{#1}}% string containing \ref
  \StrCut{\arabic{chapter}}{.}\secref@currchap\secref@trash% xstringify chapter number
  \StrCut{\Roman{section}}{.}\secref@currsec\secref@trash% xstringify section number
  \StrCut{\Alph{subsection}}{.}\secref@currsub\secref@trash% xstringify subsection number
  \StrCut{\arabic{subsubsection}}{.}\secref@currsubs\secref@trash% xstringify sub-subsection number
  \StrCut{\alph{paragraph}}{.}\secref@currpar\secref@trash% xstringify paragraph number
  \StrCut{\alph{subparagraph}\alph{subparagraph}}{.}\secref@currsubpar\secref@trash% xstringify subparagraph number
  \StrCut{\secref@rest}{.}\secref@chap\secref@rest% extract chapter number
  \StrCut{\secref@rest}{.}\secref@sec\secref@rest% extract section number
  \StrCut{\secref@rest}{.}\secref@sub\secref@rest% extract subsection number
  \StrCut{\secref@rest}{.}\secref@subs\secref@rest% extract subsubsection number
  \StrCut{\secref@rest}{.}\secref@par\secref@rest% extract parapraph number
  \StrCut{\secref@rest}{.}\secref@subpar\secref@rest% extract subparagraph number
  \edef\secref@restlink{\getrefbykeydefault{#1}{anchor}{}}% \hyperlink anchor
  \ifdefstrequal{\secref@currchap}{\secref@chap}% target in same chapter?
    {\ifdefstrequal{\secref@currsec}{\secref@sec}% target in same chapter (+); target in same section?
      {\ifdefstrequal{\secref@currsub}{\secref@sub}% target in same section (+), target in same subsection?
         {\ifdefstrequal{\secref@currsubs}{\secref@subs}% target in same subsection (+), target in same subsubsection?
           {\ifdefstrequal{\secref@currpar}{\secref@par}%target in same subsubsection (+), target in same paragraph?
             {\edef\secref@text{\secref@subpar}% target in same paragraph (+)
              \let\secref@name\secref@subparname}%
             {\edef\secref@text{\secref@par% target in same paragraph ()-)
                \ifdefvoid{\secref@subpar}%
                  {}%
                  {.\secref@subpar}}%
               \let\secref@name\secref@parname}% 
            }%
           {\edef\secref@text{\secref@subs% target in same subsubsection (-)
              \ifdefvoid{\secref@par}%
                {}%
                {.\secref@par%
                 \ifdefvoid{\secref@subpar}%
                   {}%
                   {.\secref@subpar}}%
                 }%  
             \let\secref@name\secref@subsname}% 
          }% 
         {\edef\secref@text{% target in same subsection (-)
          \secref@sub%
          \ifdefvoid{\secref@subs}%
            {}%
            {.\secref@subs%
             \ifdefvoid{\secref@par}%
              {}%
              {.\secref@par%
               \ifdefvoid{\secref@subpar}%
                 {}%
                 {.\secref@subpar}}%
               }%
             }%
           \let\secref@name\secref@subname}%
        }%
      {\edef\secref@text{% target in same section (-)
       \secref@sec%
       \ifdefvoid{\secref@sub}%
         {}%
         {.\secref@sub%
          \ifdefvoid{\secref@subs}%
           {}%
           {.\secref@subs%
             \ifdefvoid{\secref@par}%
              {}%
              {.\secref@par%
               \ifdefvoid{\secref@subpar}%
                 {}%
                 {.\secref@subpar}}%
               }%
             }%
           }%
         \let\secref@name\secref@secname}%
       }%
    {\edef\secref@text{% target in different chapter (+)
      \secref@chap%
      \ifdefvoid{\secref@sec}%
        {}%
        {:\secref@sec%
         \ifdefvoid{\secref@sub}%
           {}%
           {.\secref@sub%
            \ifdefvoid{\secref@subs}%
              {}%
              {.\secref@subs%
                \ifdefvoid{\secref@par}%
                  {}%
                  {.\secref@par%
                   \ifdefvoid{\secref@subpar}%
                     {}%
                     {.\secref@subpar}}%
                 }%
               }%
             }%
           }%
         \let\secref@name\secref@chapname}%
\hyperlink{\secref@restlink}{\secref@name\secref@text}%
\endgroup%
}%
\secref@finaldelim\relax}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{My Very First Chapter}


\section{Introduction}
\seclabel{sec:introduction}

\subsection{First Subsection of the Introduction}
\seclabel{sec:first_sub_section}

I am referencing \secref{sec:second_chapter}.

\subsubsection{First Sub-Subsection}

\paragraph{First Paragraph}
\seclabel{sec:first_paragraph}

\subparagraph{First Subparagraph}
\seclabel{sec:first_subparagraph}

\subparagraph{Second Subparagraph}

This is a reference to \secref{sec:first_subparagraph}.

\paragraph{Second Paragraph}

This is a reference to \secref{sec:first_paragraph}. And here is one to \secref{sec:first_subparagraph}.

\subsubsection{Second Sub-Subsection}

This is another reference to \secref{sec:first_subparagraph}.

\subsection{Second Subsection of the Introduction}

I am referencing \secref{sec:first_sub_section}.

\section{Once Upon a Time}

I am referencing \secref{sec:introduction}. Now I am referencing \secref{sec:first_sub_section} again.

\chapter{The Second Chapter}
\seclabel{sec:second_chapter}

I am referencing \secref{sec:first_sub_section} again.

\end{document}
```