# Changing the output of \ref depending on the position of the corresponding \label

Tags: cross-referencing

My document contains parts and sections. When I refer, for instance, to the section I.1, I would like `\ref` to output 1 when it is located in part I, and I.1 otherwise. Thus, I would like my document to look like :

I. First part
1 First section
2 Second section
Reference to the first section of the first part : 1

II. Second part
1 First section
Reference to the first section of the first part : I.1

Following [this link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208958/how-to-change-the-appearance-of-ref-depending-on-where-its-called-relative-to/209218), here is what I've tried. First, I use `\counterwithin*` so that section is reset each time part is incremented. Then, I change `\p@section` to add the part number to references to sections. Finally, I define `\newref`, which is supposed to drop the part number when it is not needed. Hence we get :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{refcount}

\counterwithin*{section}{part}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\p@section{\thepart.}
\makeatother

\newcommand\newref[1]{%
  \IfRefUndefinedExpandable{#1}{\refused{#1}\textbf{??}}{%
    \edef\temp{\expandafter\detokenize\getrefnumber{#1}}%
    \IfStrEq{\thepart}{\StrBefore\temp.}{%
      \StrBehind\temp.}{%
      \temp}}}

\begin{document}

\part{First part}

\section{First section}

\label{sec:fst}

\section{Second section}

Reference to the first section of the first part : \newref{sec:fst}

\part{Second part}

\section{First section}

Reference to the first section of the first part : \newref{sec:fst}

\end{document}
```

However, the code above fails with "! Missing { inserted", for a reason I don't understand.

So, to recap, I would greatly appreciate to :
1) Understand why my code doesn't work ;
2) Get a solution to my problem.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I think there are expansion problems and `\thepart` might not contain what you suspect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works, but it calls `\getrefnumber` three times. I'll try to improve this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{refcount}

\counterwithin*{section}{part}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\p@section{\thepart.}

%\newcommand\newref[1]{%
%  \IfRefUndefinedExpandable{#1}{\refused{#1}\textbf{??}}{%
%    \edef\temp{\expandafter\detokenize\getrefnumber{#1}}%
%    \IfStrEq{\thepart}{\StrBefore\temp.}{%
%      \StrBehind\temp.}{%
%      \temp}}}

\newcommand{\newref}[1]{%
  \IfRefUndefinedExpandable{#1}{\refused{#1}\textbf{??}}{%
    \StrBefore{\getrefnumber{#1}}{.}[\part@number]
    \StrBehind{\getrefnumber{#1}}{.}[\section@number]
    \IfStrEq{\thepart}{\part@number}{%
      \section@number%
    }{%
      \getrefnumber{#1}%
    }%
  }%
}

\makeatother


\begin{document}

\part{First part}

\section{First section}

\label{sec:fst}

\section{Second section}

Reference to the first section of the first part : \newref{sec:fst} and \newref{sec:other}

\part{Second part}

\section{First section}

Reference to the first section of the first part : \newref{sec:fst}

\end{document}
```

**Edit** Version without `\getrefnumber{#1}` called thrice:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{refcount}

\counterwithin*{section}{part}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\p@section{\thepart.}

\newcommand{\newref}[1]{%
  \IfRefUndefinedExpandable{#1}{\refused{#1}\textbf{??}}{%
    \edef\temp{\getrefnumber{#1}}%
    \StrBefore{\temp}{.}[\part@number]
    \StrBehind{\temp}{.}[\section@number]
    \IfStrEq{\thepart}{\part@number}{%
      \section@number%
    }{%
      \temp%
    }%
  }%
}

\makeatother


\begin{document}

\part{First part}

\section{First section}

\label{sec:fst}

\section{Second section}

Reference to the first section of the first part : \newref{sec:fst} and \newref{sec:other}

\part{Second part}

\section{First section}

Reference to the first section of the first part : \newref{sec:fst}

\part{Third part}

\section{First section} \label{sec:third}

Reference to the first section of the 3rd part : \newref{sec:third}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. Looking at the différences between your code and mine, I've understood a part of the problem : it is explicitly mentioned in the xstring documentation (section 3.2) that the macros of this package are not purely expandable, and that nestling them is not possible.

Comment: @aew: Yes, I mentioned that (very shortly) in my comment to your post

Comment: As for the \expandafter\detokenize sequence, I had copied it from the page I linked in my question, without being fully aware of its meaning. Apparently, not only is it useless, but it seems to make trouble. However, for some reason, the code posted in that page compiles very fine and yields the expected result.

Comment: @aew: Yes, I do not understand the detokenizing there at all. Please note, that my code my break somewhere. It's only tested for your small document.

Comment: I've tested you code in a larger document (about 40 pages and 200 references). I got 2 problems. The first seems to be a well-known, though complicated one : `\newcommand\newref` must be replaced with `\DeclareRobustCommand\newref`, otherwise references in the titles of sections may make trouble. The second problem is a very strange and unfortunate one : if we add the line `usepackage[french]{babel}` at the beginning of the file, your code doesn't work anymore. It seems to come from the reference names containing the character :. Thus, I've changed all my reference names.

Comment: For sure, in a section command, you always need a robust command or use `\protect`. And `:` is dangerous due to French typography. Both things were not available to me from your MWE.

Comment: Yes, your solution works with my MWE, but it's good to mention the problem for potential other users. I won't open a new question just for that, since there is a trivial solution : avoid using `:` in reference names. However, it goes against a well-established LaTeX tradition ; thus, if you know how Babel works, feel free to suggest something better.

Comment: Something else which is worth mentioning is that in case a section title contains a reference, patching `\ref` obviously won't affect the table of contents. Thus, there will be a slight difference between the section title announced in the table of contents, and the actual title. I don't know how to fix that (but personally, it doesn't really bother me).