# Including part and chapter numbers in cross-references

Tags: formatting, cross-referencing, cleveref

I have a project consisting of Parts, each with multiple Chapters. The Parts are written in `main.tex`, with each Chapter included as a separate `\subfile` of `main.tex`.

Is there a way to automatically include `part` and `chapter` numbering when cross-referencing a section (or lower level)?

Example `main.tex`

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref} 

\begin{document}

% Part 1
\part{}
\label{part: 1}

% Include chapter 1
\subfile{Pt1/Ch1}

\end{document}
```

Example `chapter` subfile

```
\documentclass[../main.tex]{subfiles}

\begin{document}

\Chapter{My first chapter}

\section{My first section}

\subsection{My first subsection}
\label{SS: My first subsection}

\section{My second section}

In \ref{SS: My first subsection} we discussed...

\end{document}
```

where I'm looking for the `\ref` command to generate a cross-reference of the form:

> In Pt 1, Ch 1, 1.1 we discussed...

Thank you for your help.

Comment: This https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/252994/changing-the-output-of-ref-depending-on-the-position-of-the-corresponding-labe will helps you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this achieve what you want?

You can define the label format for section and subsection using command `\labelformat{<target heading>}{<format>}`.

Such as:

> main.tex

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\labelformat{section}{Pt~\arabic{part}, Ch~\thechapter, \thesection}
\labelformat{subsection}{Pt~\arabic{part}, Ch~\thechapter, \thesubsection}

\begin{document}

% Part 1
\part{}
\label{part: 1}

% Include chapter 1
\subfile{Pt1/Ch1}

\end{document}
```

> `chapter` subfile

```
\documentclass[../main.tex]{subfiles}

\begin{document}

\chapter{My first chapter}

\section{My first section}
\label{S: My first section}
\subsection{My first subsection}
\label{SS: My first subsection}

\section{My second section}

In \ref{SS: My first subsection} we discussed... In \ref{S: My first section} we discussed...

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is excellent, thank you. At the risk of digressing - is it possible to also include the title of a section within `\labelformat`  , to generate something like "In Pt1, Ch1, My first section 1.1 we discussed..." ?

Comment: The above query solved in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/706371/including-subsection-titles-in-label-using-labelformat/706374#706374).

Comment: @Bells12 Sorry for late response. I am glad the problem has been solved.