# Include/exclude section number in equation references depending on where the reference appears?

Tags: cleveref

I'd like to have references to an equation exclude the section number when the equation is referenced within the same section, but include it when it's referenced in a different section.

Here's an example of what I'm attempting to obtain:
[image: Desired result]
Here's what I've tried, and I have a pretty good idea of what's wrong with it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}}
\creflabelformat{equation}{#2(\thesection.#1)#3}

\begin{document}
\section{The first section}\label{first}

This is the some disussion in \cref{first}. This is the first equation:
\begin{equation}\label{A:1}
  1+1 = 2
\end{equation}
This is some more disussion. Here is a reference to \cref{A:1}.

\section{The second section}\label{second}
\setcounter{equation}{0}

This is some discussion in \cref{second} which references \cref{first}.
This is another equation:
\begin{equation}\label{B:1}
  2+2 = 4
\end{equation}
This is some discussion of \cref{B:1}, and a brief comment that it is
easily derived from equation \cref{A:1}.

\end{document}
```

[image: First attempt]

Unfortunately, I don't know how get the result I'm looking for.

Comment: As a reader, I must confess this format of numbering is extremely confusing. I remembered a textbook on probability theory written in this fashion and I was so confused that I decided to switch to another book altogether. You’re basically asking the readers to decide whether a section number should be prepend to an equation number, which makes your complicated math even more difficult to understand.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208958/how-to-change-the-appearance-of-ref-depending-on-where-its-called-relative-to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using an `expl3` solution based on Marcel Krüger's answer:

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Npn \ifsection #1#2#3 {
  \str_if_eq_x:nnTF{\thesection}{#1}{#2}{#3}
}
\cs_new:Npn \ifcurrentsection #1#2 { \ifsection{\thesection}{#1}{#2} } 

\renewcommand\theequation{
  \ifcurrentsection{}{\thesection.}\arabic{equation}
}  
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

This allowed me to be a little more flexible and change the behavior depending whether the reference appears in the current section or a different one.

Answer (score 1):

I can only agree with the comment from Ruixi Zhang: This format often is confusing for the reader and I strongly advice against using it.

If you still want to implement it, you have to modify `theequation` instead of setting `creflabelformat` because `creflabelformat` is only evaluated when the label is referenced. At this point, the original section the equation was in is already lost.

To skip the section if it is the same as the section containing the reference, I defined a small macro. This currently only works for pdfTeX but `\pdfstrcmp` could easily be replaced by `expl3`'s `\str_if_eq_x:nnF` to be compatible with more engines.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\DeclareRobustCommand\skipifequals[2]{%
  \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{#1}{#2}=0
  \else
    #2%
  \fi
}
\newcommand\skipifcurrent[1]{\protecting{\skipifequals{#1}}{#1}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}}
\creflabelformat{equation}{#2(#1)#3}
\renewcommand\theequation{\skipifcurrent{\thesection.}\arabic{equation}}

\begin{document}
\section{The first section}\label{first}

This is the some disussion in \cref{first}. This is the first equation:
\begin{equation}\label{A:1}
  1+1 = 2
\end{equation}
This is some more disussion. Here is a reference to \cref{A:1}.

\section{The second section}\label{second}
\setcounter{equation}{0}

This is some discussion in \cref{second} which references \cref{first}.
This is another equation:
\begin{equation}\label{B:1}
  2+2 = 4
\end{equation}
This is some discussion of \cref{B:1}, and a brief comment that it is
easily derived from equation \cref{A:1}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I haven't found a reference to `\str_compare_x:nnF` anywhere in my current expl3 documentation. Presumably you mean `\str_if_eq_x:nnF`?